# Sqlite with dynamic fields in table in ionic framework

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Sqlite for local storage in my ionic2 application, where I am generating a dynamic form based on json response from api. currently my json is providing 3 fields, id, name, email in future I will add some more fields.

```
if (!this.isOpen) {
      this.storage = new SQLite();
      this.storage.create({ name: "data.db", location: "default" }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.db = db;
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, email Text)", []);
        this.isOpen = true;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

How would I make my sqlite object dynamic, as much as fields are added to json response it should keep/save those values in same table, is there a way to make a generic way of declaring table query in sqlite.

```
 CreateUser(name:string, email:string){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      let sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)";
      this.db.executeSql(sql, [name, email]).then((data) =>{
        resolve(data);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you already get a answer for this question? Did you get to create and insert dynamic data into a local sqlite table? Thanks

Comment: @WillBinLopesCordeiro This is a very old thread, I honestly even don't remember, why I asked this? However, I remember that somehow, it was done.